# ReferenceError: variable is not defined when importing from another module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

`index.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { master, setMaster } from './variableTest'

export default Home () {
  [signedIn, setSignedIn] = React.useState(false)
  [master, setMaster] = React.useState([])

  return (<>...</>)
}
```

`variableTest.js`

```js
var master, setMaster

export default master
export { master, setMaster }
```

Now, `signedIn` is `[]`, but `master` and `setMaster` is still undefined.

I added `;` to the end of `[signedIn, setSignedIn] = React.useState(false)`:

`index.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { master, setMaster } from './variableTest'

export default Home () {
  [signedIn, setSignedIn] = React.useState(false);
  [master, setMaster] = React.useState([])

  return (<>...</>)
}
```

[image: The screenshot of the error]

And a error occured: `master` is not defined.

I want to give `master` and `setMaster` a new value when `Home()` built.

Comment: `export default Home () {` isn't valid syntax, to start with. Also, you do not have `{ variable, setVariable }` in `variableTest`, but `master, setMaster`. Can you fix the typos first?

Comment: `export { master, setMaster }` is named export which means you have to import them by that name only `import { master, setMaster } from './variableTest'`

Comment: is Home a functional component?